# Mapinfo 10 with new look does not show toggle state of button

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

Is this only a problem to me or a problem to other's too. I have mapbasic application that runs good on mapinfo 11 and mapinfo 10 with old look but this toggle button does not work with mapinfo 10 (The icons dll files too won't work) . What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps any one :- Actually the problem was with the resolution of the screen. Mapinfo buttons does not work properly with certain resolution usually lower resolution.